# how to display the results of a twitter analysis that is in a dataframe to frontend in django

Tags: html, pandas, django-views

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def tweetsPageView(request):
    #reload(sys)

    #sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    with open("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Movie-Review-Prediction-SentimentAnalysis-master/"
              "Project code Group_17/mywebsite/Filmatory/pandas.csv",
              'r',encoding="utf8") as read_file:
```

Comment: i trie to save teh data in a csv file to call it, but im having issues and considering calling it from the views.py directly

Comment: Your code is incomplete, please try to post a complete piece of code.